when do I use "dangerouslysetinnerhtml"in my react code?
I am not able to understand when to use it and why it is phrased as "dangerous" as i have seen a number of coders using it in their codes.I need a clarification on when do I use it and how am yet to understand it as I have ony seeing, used and heard of it today.
i was constructing a component that consist of a question card as I was trying to build or create a quiz site that asks random questions .
As i was looking for ways to do it I came across the "dangerouslytsetinnerhtml".Though i am not yet convinced on how it works.and is there an alternative ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. Also setting setting HTML like this is prone to cross-site scripting attacks. So technically anyone should avoid using it until the input for it is completely immutable.
Also answering for your question to alternatives to it you have some npm packages like DOMPurify
Also if your application requires using an HTML as string you can look into html-to-react

Not "completely immutable", but "completely under developer's control". It may safely come from database that you (not your users!) populate, or be generated dynamically from some (unknown) subset of literal strings, and that still opens no door for XSS.

Yes i meant that only thanks for the elaboration
